# Fill Multiple select when editing a post

Tags: php, forms, zend-framework

I am making a blog in Zend Framework. At this moment I am making the page to edit a blogpost.

I have a multiple select element. It gets his data out of the database. it's a list with tags.
when I edit a blogpost, it shows the list in my form filled with all possible tags. Now, I want to set some values selected.(the tags that belong to the post as in the database selected).

Is that possible?

**in my form i do this to make the multiple select with values**

```
    //create form element
    $tags = $this->createElement('multiselect','tags');

    //get all tags out DB
    $tags_model = new Application_Model_DbTable_Tags();
    $tags_array = $tags_model->getAll();

    //fill the element with the tags
    foreach ($tags_array as $tag){
          $tags->addMultiOption($tag['id'], $tag['name']);
      }
```

**controller where i call the form:**
It gets the data from the blogpost and populates it in the form.

```
         $blogpost = new Application_Model_DbTable_Blogposts();
         $data = $blogpost->load($id);
         $form->populate($blogpost->load($id));
```

SOLUTION:

```
$tags->setValue(array(1,4));
```

i must write the solution here because:

```
 "Oops! Your answer couldn't be submitted because:
 Users with less than 100 reputation can't answer their own question for 8 hours after   asking. You may self-answer in 7 hours. Until then please use comments, or edit   your   question instead."
```

Comment: I would say yes but since you don't show us any markup or code it won't be definitive.

Answer (score 0):

See the [MultiSelect](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.form.standardElements.html#zend.form.standardElements.multiselect) documentation. Call addMultiOptions() with all values and then setMultOptions() on the sub-set of selected values from the DB.

Comment: nope, that replaces all other tags and it doesn't select a tag.